# ansible playbook doesnot recognicise '*' regular expression

Tags: ansible, cp

```yaml
- name: Copy shipped media files on to symlink
  shell: '/bin/cp -Rf /opt/omnius/ose/media.bak/* /var/opt/ose_media/'
```

the below tasks failed with below error

```
fatal: [nl3832yr]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/bin/cp", "-Rf", "/opt/omnius/ose/media.bak/*", "/var/opt/ose_media/"], "delta": "0:00:00.004059", "end": "2021-04-15 17:13:31.123072", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-04-15 17:13:31.119013", "stderr": "/bin/cp: cannot stat ‘/opt/omnius/ose/media.bak/*’: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/cp: cannot stat ‘/opt/omnius/ose/media.bak/*’: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

seems ansible doesn't recognize `*`

Comment: Technically speaking, you are using a shell glob, not a regular expresion. This glob would not give the expected result used as a regexp since `/*` would match "zero or more forward slashes" and you would need `/.*` ("forward slash and zero or more characters)

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything to do with ansible directly, as ansible will execute the line as-is in a shell. So the shell you are using does not resolve the `*`.
You can change that by using this:

```yaml
- name: Copy shipped media files on to symlink
  shell: '/bin/cp -Rf /opt/omnius/ose/media.bak/* /var/opt/ose_media/'
    executable: /bin/bash
```

But you should actually use the [copy-module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) with the `remote_src` parameter like this:

```yaml
- name: Copy shipped media files on to symlink
  copy:
    src: /opt/omnius/ose/media.bak/
    dest: /var/opt/ose_media/
    remote_src: yes
```

It is always better to use ansible modules than the `shell` module.

Comment: its a remote-remote copy directory so copy module wont work

Comment: Yes, it does, you need to use the `remote_src` option, as I wrote in the answer, you can see it in the example

Comment: i need only content of the media.bak folder not the whole die itself

Comment: the `/` at the end of the `src` does exactly that

Comment: @dharb2 please accept my answer by clicking on the tick-mark left of it